# How to implement a dialogue/quest system in a javascript game?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, game-engine

I've been looking around for any examples and implementations of a dialogue/quest system on the internet, and could find much on javascript. Mostly Unity tutorials, and those are on C#.

So I'm running a node.js server, and an html5 client with phaser.io framework. I'm planning to use some kind of a DOM method with JQuery to display stuff to client. Now how is it done on the server side? How is it stored? JSON file for example could hold keys, text, etc, but then it's kind of not very readable, and not secure since it could be fetched from the server. Database, on the other hand is much more secure, but more seems to me more inconvenient to store such data.

Then, after the storing method has been implemented, how do you call those dialogue trees from where they are stored, how do you send them, and so on. Could somebody explain to me how it's done in the field with most browser games, and other RPGs? Is it really efficient to emit a socket to fetch a particular dialogue/script? I'd think some sort of a automated general script could do the job, but I don't even know where to start!

Thank you!